# Placing total on the bottom of DIV

Tags: html, css

The numbers on the bottom of each column represent the sum of the values of each column.

What do I need to change to have all the total values allign at the same level at the bottom of the page, just above the slider?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

    /* The number of event sections / years with events */
    var tot=$('.event').length;

    $('.eventList li').click(function(e){
            showWindow('<div>'+$(this).find('div.content').html()+'</div>');
    });

    /* Each event section is 320 px wide */
    var timelineWidth = 320*tot;
    var screenWidth = $(document).width();

    $('#timelineScroll').width(timelineWidth);

    /* If the timeline is wider than the screen show the slider: */
    if(timelineWidth > screenWidth)
    {
        $('#scroll,#slider').show();
        $('#centered,#slider').width(120*tot);

        /* Making the scrollbar draggable: */
        $('#bar').width((120/320)*screenWidth).draggable({

            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function(e, ui) {

                if(!this.elem)
                {
                    /* This section is executed only the first time the function is run for performance */

                    this.elem = $('#timelineScroll');

                    /* The difference between the slider's width and its container: */
                    this.maxSlide = ui.helper.parent().width()-ui.helper.width();

                    /* The difference between the timeline's width and its container */
                    this.cWidth = this.elem.width()-this.elem.parent().width();
                    this.highlight = $('#highlight');
                }

                /* Translating each movement of the slider to the timeline: */
                this.elem.css({marginLeft:'-'+((ui.position.left/this.maxSlide)*this.cWidth)+'px'});

                /* Moving the highlight: */
                this.highlight.css('left',ui.position.left)
            }
        });

        $('#highlight').width((120/320)*screenWidth-3);
    }

});

function showWindow(data)
{
 /* Each event contains a set of hidden divs that hold
    additional information about the event: */
    
 var producto = $('.producto',data).text();
 var date = $('.date',data).text();
 var body = $('.body',data).html();
 
 $('<div id="overlay">').css({
        
  width:$(document).width(),
  height:$(document).height(),
  opacity:0.6
  
 }).appendTo('body').click(function(){
  
  $(this).remove();
  $('#windowBox').remove();
  
 });
 
 $('body').append('<div id="windowBox"><div id="productoDiv">'+producto+'</div>'+body+'<div id="date">'+date+'</div></div>');

 $('#windowBox').css({
  width:500,
  height:350,
  left: ($(window).width() - 500)/2,
  top: ($(window).height() - 350)/2
 });
 
}/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
```

```css
body,h1,h2,h3,p,quote,small,form,input,ul,li,ol,label{
 /* Simple page reset */
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body{
 /* Setting default text color, background and a font stack */
 color:#555555;
 font-size:0.825em;
 background: #fcfcfc;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.event{
 /* Contains the event header and body list */
 float:left;
 padding:4px;
 text-align:left;
 width:300px;
 margin:0 5px 50px;
}

.eventList li{
 /* The individual events */
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 list-style:none;
 margin:5px;
 padding:4px 7px;
 
 /* CSS3 rounded corners */
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius:4px;
}

.eventList li:hover{
 /* The hover state: */
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

li span{
 /* The event icon */
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:16px;
 margin-right:5px;
 width:16px;
}

/* Individual background images for each type of event: */

li.news span.icon {  background:url(../img/icons/newspaper.png) no-repeat; }
li.image span.icon {  background:url(../img/icons/camera.png) no-repeat; }
li.milestone span.icon {  background:url(../img/icons/chart.png) no-repeat; }

div.content{
 /* This div contains additional data for the content */
 display:none;
}

.eventHeading{
 /* The colorful year headings at the top */
 font-size:2em;
 margin:-5px -5px 10px;
 padding:2px 5px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Three color styles for the headings: */

.eventHeading.chreme{
 background:#FBF7F0;
 border:1px solid #EEE4D4;
 color:#A78B5F;
}

.eventHeading.blue{
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

.eventHeading.green{
 background:#E6FFDF none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border:1px solid #C9E6C1;
 color:#6EA85F;
}

#timelineLimiter{
 /* Hides the overflowing timeline */
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:40px 0;
}

#scroll{
 /* The small timeline below the main one. Hidden here and shown by jQuery if JS is enabled: */
 display:none;
 height:30px;

 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#999999;
}

.scrollPoints{
 /* The individual years */
 float:left;
 font-size:1.4em;
 padding:4px 10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100px;
 
 position:relative;
 z-index:10;
}

#centered{
 /* Centers the years, width is assigned by jQuery */
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
}

#slider{
 /* Holds the scroll bar */
 margin:10px auto;
 height:25px;
 display:none;
}

#bar{
 /* The scroll bar */
 background:url(../img/slider_center.png) repeat-x center center;
 height:25px;
 cursor:pointer;
        
        z-index:999;  /* make it on top of others */
        

}

#barLeft{
 background:transparent url(../img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
 height:25px;
 width:20px;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 position:absolute;
}

#barRight{
 background:transparent url(../img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
 height:25px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:20px;
}

#overlay{
 /* The overlay that darkens the page when an event is clicked */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:#222222;
}

#windowBox{
 /* Shows details about the event on click */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:20;
 background-color:#fcfcfc;
 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid #666666;
 overflow:auto;
}

#titleDiv{
 /* The title of the windowBox */
 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#AAAAAA;
 font-size:1.5em;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 padding:5px 10px;
}

#date{
 /* The date on the bottom of the windowBox */
 bottom:20px;
 color:#999999;
 font-size:0.8em;
 font-style:italic;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 padding:2px;
 background:#FCFCFC;
}

#highlight{
 /* The blue highlight that moves with the scroll bar */
 height:30px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:0;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 border-width:0 1px;
}

.clear{
 clear:both;
}

/* The styles below are only necessary for the demo page */

h1{
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-bottom:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 padding:15px;
 text-align:center;
}

h2 {
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding-right:40px;
 position:relative;
 right:0;
 text-align:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 top:-48px;
}

a, a:visited {
 color:#0196e3;
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:none;
}

a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

p.tutInfo{
 /* The tutorial info on the bottom of the page */
 padding:10px 0;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 width:100%;
}
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : Feb 18, 2017, 12:11:54 PM
    Author     : Rodrigo
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
 
 
    <div id="timelineLimiter"> <!-- Hides the overflowing timelineScroll div -->
     <div id="timelineScroll"> <!-- Contains the timeline and expands to fit -->

  
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Nov -0001</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Pala</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">0</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Pala</div>
     <div class="date">November 30, -0001</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>0</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">May 2015</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Enfriadores Azul</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Enfriadores Azul</div>
     <div class="date">May 14, 2015</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,592,100</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo</div>
     <div class="date">May 30, 2015</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>3,392,100</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Puntilla con Cabeza 2pulg Propack 5kg</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">5,100,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Puntilla con Cabeza 2pulg Propack 5kg</div>
     <div class="date">February 5, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>5,100,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Apr 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">6,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">3,276,430</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Vitaperico1 Kg</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">72</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Vitaperico1 Kg</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">400</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">28</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>10,076,934</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Jul 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Escobilla Limpiafondo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,240,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Escobilla Limpiafondo</div>
     <div class="date">July 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,240,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Aug 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Espatula Extra Ancha</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">42</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Espatula Extra Ancha</div>
     <div class="date">August 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>42</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Sep 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">280,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</div>
     <div class="date">September 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>280,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Oct 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">336,002,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</div>
     <div class="date">October 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>336,001,664</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2021</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Guante Tipo Examen Nitrilo Tallla S x 100 Und</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,408</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Guante Tipo Examen Nitrilo Tallla S x 100 Und</div>
     <div class="date">February 2, 2021</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,408</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Sep 2022</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,750,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</div>
     <div class="date">September 18, 2022</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,750,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Nov 2022</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">308,025</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo</div>
     <div class="date">November 25, 2022</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>308,025</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Apr 2030</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">750,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</div>
     <div class="date">April 16, 2030</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>750,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Nov 2098</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo refractario 24x12,5x4 1,5 kilos 36u/m2...</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">54</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo refractario 24x12,5x4 1,5 kilos 36u/m2...</div>
     <div class="date">November 25, 2098</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>54</h1></ul></div>     
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="scroll"> <!-- The year time line -->
            <div id="centered"> <!-- Sized by jQuery to fit all the years -->
             <div id="highlight"></div> <!-- The light blue highlight shown behind the years -->
             <div class="scrollPoints">Nov -0001</div><div class="scrollPoints">May 2015</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Apr 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Jul 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Aug 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Sep 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Oct 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2021</div><div class="scrollPoints">Sep 2022</div><div class="scrollPoints">Nov 2022</div><div class="scrollPoints">Apr 2030</div><div class="scrollPoints">Nov 2098</div> <!-- This PHP variable holds the years that have events -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="slider"> <!-- The slider container -->
         <div id="bar"> <!-- The bar that can be dragged -->
             <div id="barLeft"></div>  <!-- Left arrow of the bar -->
                <div id="barRight"></div>  <!-- Right arrow, both are styled with CSS -->
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </div> 

   <
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want consistent looks, it's probably better to use a `<table>` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Style**

`position: absolute;bottom: 0; width: 268px;` in  **h1 tag**

`position: relative;margin-bottom: 15px;` in  **#timelineScroll**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

    /* The number of event sections / years with events */
    var tot=$('.event').length;

    $('.eventList li').click(function(e){
            showWindow('<div>'+$(this).find('div.content').html()+'</div>');
    });

    /* Each event section is 320 px wide */
    var timelineWidth = 320*tot;
    var screenWidth = $(document).width();

    $('#timelineScroll').width(timelineWidth);

    /* If the timeline is wider than the screen show the slider: */
    if(timelineWidth > screenWidth)
    {
        $('#scroll,#slider').show();
        $('#centered,#slider').width(120*tot);

        /* Making the scrollbar draggable: */
        $('#bar').width((120/320)*screenWidth).draggable({

            containment: 'parent',
            drag: function(e, ui) {

                if(!this.elem)
                {
                    /* This section is executed only the first time the function is run for performance */

                    this.elem = $('#timelineScroll');

                    /* The difference between the slider's width and its container: */
                    this.maxSlide = ui.helper.parent().width()-ui.helper.width();

                    /* The difference between the timeline's width and its container */
                    this.cWidth = this.elem.width()-this.elem.parent().width();
                    this.highlight = $('#highlight');
                }

                /* Translating each movement of the slider to the timeline: */
                this.elem.css({marginLeft:'-'+((ui.position.left/this.maxSlide)*this.cWidth)+'px'});

                /* Moving the highlight: */
                this.highlight.css('left',ui.position.left)
            }
        });

        $('#highlight').width((120/320)*screenWidth-3);
    }

});

function showWindow(data)
{
 /* Each event contains a set of hidden divs that hold
    additional information about the event: */
    
 var producto = $('.producto',data).text();
 var date = $('.date',data).text();
 var body = $('.body',data).html();
 
 $('<div id="overlay">').css({
        
  width:$(document).width(),
  height:$(document).height(),
  opacity:0.6
  
 }).appendTo('body').click(function(){
  
  $(this).remove();
  $('#windowBox').remove();
  
 });
 
 $('body').append('<div id="windowBox"><div id="productoDiv">'+producto+'</div>'+body+'<div id="date">'+date+'</div></div>');

 $('#windowBox').css({
  width:500,
  height:350,
  left: ($(window).width() - 500)/2,
  top: ($(window).height() - 350)/2
 });
 
}/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
```

```css
body,h1,h2,h3,p,quote,small,form,input,ul,li,ol,label{
 /* Simple page reset */
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body{
 /* Setting default text color, background and a font stack */
 color:#555555;
 font-size:0.825em;
 background: #fcfcfc;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.event{
 /* Contains the event header and body list */
 float:left;
 padding:4px;
 text-align:left;
 width:300px;
 margin:0 5px 50px;
}

.eventList li{
 /* The individual events */
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 list-style:none;
 margin:5px;
 padding:4px 7px;
 
 /* CSS3 rounded corners */
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius:4px;
}

.eventList li:hover{
 /* The hover state: */
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

li span{
 /* The event icon */
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:16px;
 margin-right:5px;
 width:16px;
}

/* Individual background images for each type of event: */

li.news span.icon {  background:url(../img/icons/newspaper.png) no-repeat; }
li.image span.icon {  background:url(../img/icons/camera.png) no-repeat; }
li.milestone span.icon {  background:url(../img/icons/chart.png) no-repeat; }

div.content{
 /* This div contains additional data for the content */
 display:none;
}

.eventHeading{
 /* The colorful year headings at the top */
 font-size:2em;
 margin:-5px -5px 10px;
 padding:2px 5px;
 text-align:center;
}

/* Three color styles for the headings: */

.eventHeading.chreme{
 background:#FBF7F0;
 border:1px solid #EEE4D4;
 color:#A78B5F;
}

.eventHeading.blue{
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 color:#548DA5;
}

.eventHeading.green{
 background:#E6FFDF none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border:1px solid #C9E6C1;
 color:#6EA85F;
}

#timelineLimiter{
 /* Hides the overflowing timeline */
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:40px 0;
}
#timelineScroll{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#scroll{
 /* The small timeline below the main one. Hidden here and shown by jQuery if JS is enabled: */
 display:none;
 height:30px;

 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#999999;
}

.scrollPoints{
 /* The individual years */
 float:left;
 font-size:1.4em;
 padding:4px 10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:100px;
 
 position:relative;
 z-index:10;
}

#centered{
 /* Centers the years, width is assigned by jQuery */
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
}

#slider{
 /* Holds the scroll bar */
 margin:10px auto;
 height:25px;
 display:none;
}

#bar{
 /* The scroll bar */
 background:url(../img/slider_center.png) repeat-x center center;
 height:25px;
 cursor:pointer;
        
        z-index:999;  /* make it on top of others */
        

}

#barLeft{
 background:transparent url(../img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
 height:25px;
 width:20px;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 position:absolute;
}

#barRight{
 background:transparent url(../img/slider.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
 height:25px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 width:20px;
}

#overlay{
 /* The overlay that darkens the page when an event is clicked */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:#222222;
}

#windowBox{
 /* Shows details about the event on click */
 position:absolute;
 z-index:20;
 background-color:#fcfcfc;
 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid #666666;
 overflow:auto;
}

#titleDiv{
 /* The title of the windowBox */
 background:#F5F5F5;
 border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color:#AAAAAA;
 font-size:1.5em;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 padding:5px 10px;
}

#date{
 /* The date on the bottom of the windowBox */
 bottom:20px;
 color:#999999;
 font-size:0.8em;
 font-style:italic;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 padding:2px;
 background:#FCFCFC;
}

#highlight{
 /* The blue highlight that moves with the scroll bar */
 height:30px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:0;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 
 background:#E6F8FF;
 border:1px solid #D4E6EE;
 border-width:0 1px;
}

.clear{
 clear:both;
}

/* The styles below are only necessary for the demo page */

h1{
 background: #F4F4F4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 4px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 268px;
}

h2 {
 font-family:"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding-right:40px;
 position:relative;
 right:0;
 text-align:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 top:-48px;
}

a, a:visited {
 color:#0196e3;
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:none;
}

a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

p.tutInfo{
 /* The tutorial info on the bottom of the page */
 padding:10px 0;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 background:#F4F4F4;
 border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;
 width:100%;
}
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : Feb 18, 2017, 12:11:54 PM
    Author     : Rodrigo
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
 
 
    <div id="timelineLimiter"> <!-- Hides the overflowing timelineScroll div -->
     <div id="timelineScroll"> <!-- Contains the timeline and expands to fit -->

  
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Nov -0001</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Pala</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">0</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Pala</div>
     <div class="date">November 30, -0001</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>0</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">May 2015</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Enfriadores Azul</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Enfriadores Azul</div>
     <div class="date">May 14, 2015</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,592,100</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo</div>
     <div class="date">May 30, 2015</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>3,392,100</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Puntilla con Cabeza 2pulg Propack 5kg</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">5,100,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Puntilla con Cabeza 2pulg Propack 5kg</div>
     <div class="date">February 5, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>5,100,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Apr 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">6,800,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Varilla 5/8 pulgada x 6 metros cuadrada</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">3,276,430</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Segueta 24 dientes paquete 10 unidades 3906-300...</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Vitaperico1 Kg</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">72</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Vitaperico1 Kg</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">400</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Llanta 275/55 Rin 20 111S CC LX20</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">28</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Parasol Lateral 3 m Blanco</div>
     <div class="date">April 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>10,076,934</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Jul 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Escobilla Limpiafondo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,240,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Escobilla Limpiafondo</div>
     <div class="date">July 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,240,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Aug 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Espatula Extra Ancha</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">42</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Espatula Extra Ancha</div>
     <div class="date">August 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>42</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Sep 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">280,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Guantes Hilaza Neon Puntos PVC 2 Caras</div>
     <div class="date">September 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>280,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Oct 2017</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">336,002,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo hor 3 huecos 9x20x80 9.5k 6.25und/m2</div>
     <div class="date">October 14, 2017</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>336,001,664</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Feb 2021</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Guante Tipo Examen Nitrilo Tallla S x 100 Und</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,408</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Guante Tipo Examen Nitrilo Tallla S x 100 Und</div>
     <div class="date">February 2, 2021</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,408</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Sep 2022</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">1,750,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Alambre #8 100 metros amarillo Conectores y Cables</div>
     <div class="date">September 18, 2022</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>1,750,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading blue">Nov 2022</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">308,025</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo</div>
     <div class="date">November 25, 2022</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>308,025</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading chreme">Apr 2030</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">750,000,000</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Asoleadora Curva Chocolate</div>
     <div class="date">April 16, 2030</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>750,000,000</h1></ul></div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="eventHeading green">Nov 2098</div>
                <ul class="eventList">
                <li class=""><table><tr>
    <th>Ladrillo refractario 24x12,5x4 1,5 kilos 36u/m2...</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">54</th>
    </table></tr>
    <div class="content">
                                
     <div class="body"></div>
     <div class="producto">Ladrillo refractario 24x12,5x4 1,5 kilos 36u/m2...</div>
     <div class="date">November 25, 2098</div>
    </div>
    
    </li><h1>54</h1></ul></div>     
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="scroll"> <!-- The year time line -->
            <div id="centered"> <!-- Sized by jQuery to fit all the years -->
             <div id="highlight"></div> <!-- The light blue highlight shown behind the years -->
             <div class="scrollPoints">Nov -0001</div><div class="scrollPoints">May 2015</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Apr 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Jul 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Aug 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Sep 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Oct 2017</div><div class="scrollPoints">Feb 2021</div><div class="scrollPoints">Sep 2022</div><div class="scrollPoints">Nov 2022</div><div class="scrollPoints">Apr 2030</div><div class="scrollPoints">Nov 2098</div> <!-- This PHP variable holds the years that have events -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="slider"> <!-- The slider container -->
         <div id="bar"> <!-- The bar that can be dragged -->
             <div id="barLeft"></div>  <!-- Left arrow of the bar -->
                <div id="barRight"></div>  <!-- Right arrow, both are styled with CSS -->
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </div> 

   <
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The columns on the bottom of the columns to not allign at the bottom.

Comment: all row width same align ?? example row `Nov-0001` after row `Pala 0` and total are width same as row `Nov-0001`  ??

Comment: I want to allign the totals at the end of each column


0            3.392.000         5.100.000         etc.

Comment: ok. i updated my answer . check it any other query put comment

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!